# No such file or directory:

Tags: python, deep-learning, jupyter-notebook, conv-neural-network, image-classification

I am running my code in Jupyter notebook for image classification and it gives me an error of "No such file or directory:" I have checked the directory by
`isdirr = os.path.isdir(x) isfilee = os.path.isfile(x)`
and for it's TRUE for isdirr but when I run my code, it gives me an error.
The code is given below

```
root_dir = 'Try'
datasets = {x: datasets.ImageFolder(root = os.path.join(root_dir, x), 
                                    transform = data_transforms[x])
            for x in ['Train', 'Validate']}
dataloaders = {x: torch.utils.data.DataLoader(datasets[x], batch_size=4, 
                                              shuffle=True, num_workers=0)
            for x in ['Train', 'Validate']}
sizes = {x: len(datasets[x]) for x in ['Train', 'Validate']}
class_names = datasets['Train'].classes
device = torch.device("cuda:0" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")
```

The "Try" is a directory which contain sub directories "test" and "train" which further contains 2 directories of flowering and non_flowering images each.
It will be great if someone can help. After a lot of research, I am unable to solve it. This is a very common problem and not getting solved.

Comment: check where you are exectuing the code from, and whether this is were you want to be. You can do this with os.getcwd()

Comment: @warped it's in the same working directory

Comment: Please give me that repository?

Comment: either rename your folders to `Train` and `Validate` or loop over `train` and `test` in your code.

Comment: @Kreimben here is the repository https://github.com/muradali4442/Plant_phenology

Comment: @warped I have changed the names too but it's not working, maybe there is such problem ".ipynb_checkpoints"